# Fastlane - Code Signing - Push Notifications ERROR

Tags: react-native, push-notification, code-signing, fastlane

I do have an application that uses `Push Notifications` service and crashes on `gym` (I'm using Fastlane tool for releasing) step (**pay attention**) if I **don't simply open** that application in Xcode. This is the error I receive on `gym`:

:x: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the Push Notifications capability.

:x: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement.

:x: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

If I do open (just open, I'm not even building it) the created application into Xcode (after application is succesfully initialized into Xcode) the `gym` step would sucessfully fulfill.

I'm searching a solution that would process the project somehow automatically without opening the application in Xcode,

What I've tried to do:

### A.

```
1. automatic_code_signing(use_automatic_signing: false, path: "demo.xcodeproj")
2. gym(include_bitcode: false, clean: true)
3. automatic_code_signing(use_automatic_signing: false, path: "demo.xcodeproj")
```

### B.

Other `72398714918274` steps to get rid of that error. Ex:

```
# Fastfile
lane :getRidOfThatStickyIssue do
  produce(
    # other options
    enable_services: {
      push_notification: "on"
    }   
  )

  sigh

  cert

  automatic_code_signing(
    #set to true
  )

  gym(
    # path, project, etc.
  )
end
```

### C.

I've made a diff to changes to see what values or files changed in the project, after the project is opened in Xcode, and there's none.

Ps.: I have tried also possible solutions from

1. [link_1](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6533)
2. [link_2](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6333)
3. [link_3](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6544#issuecomment-253858562)

No valid solution found. :(